# Sort a list of generic interface

Tags: java, generics, sorting, collections, interface

Here is the case, I have two classes `A`, `B`, and a generic interface `C`

```
Class A implements Comparable<A> {...}

interface C<T> {...}

//this class is not longer generic type, I do not know if this matter.
Class B extends A implements C<A> {...}
```

Then, at other class, I got a `B` List and sort it as follow

```
List<B> list = new ArrayList<B>();
Collections.sort(list);
```

This works perfectly, but now I would like to change the list of `B` to the generic interface `C`, so that it can be more general.

```
List<C<A>> list = new ArrayList<C<A>>();
Collections.sort(list);
```

This time I got the Error as follow:

> Bound mismatch: The generic method `sort(List<T>)` of type `Collections` is not
>   applicable for the arguments `(List<C<A>>)`. The inferred type `C<A>` is not a
>   valid substitute for the bounded parameter `<T extends Comparable<? super T>>`

I have tried the following modifications (of course does not work):

1. change `C` to `interface C<T> extends Comparable<T>{...}`
2. change `B` to `class B extends A implements C<A>, Comparable<T> {...}`

Can anybody help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> change C to interface C extends Comparable{...}
>   Class B extends A implements C {...}

As you would have already seen from the error messages, these two won't work together as there will be a conflict in `B`'s definition w.r.t to `Comparable<A>` and `Comparable<C<A>>`.

Since `A` is already implementing `Comparable<A>`, you can achieve the following

```
List<C<A>> list = new ArrayList<C<A>>();
Collections.sort(list);
```

by defining a `Comparator` for `C<A>` as follows:

```
class CTComparator<T> implements Comparator<C<T>>
{
    @Override
    public int compare(C<T> o1, C<T> o2)
    {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

and then applying the sort method with this comparator:

```
List<C<T>> list  = new ArrayList<C<T>>();
Collections.sort(list, comparator);
```

Answer (score 1):

Since `C<A>` is not having the visibility of the `Comparator` defined in `A` hence it's complaining. Define a new comparator of `C<A>` as blow, it should be fine then.

```
List<C<A>> list = new ArrayList<C<A>>();
Collections.sort(list, new Comparator<C<A>>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(C<A> o1, C<A> o2) {
        //implement the comarison
        return 0;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

If you expect `C<T>` to be generically comparable based on the type it contains, you should make it comparable on itself (`C<T>`, not `T`), but bound its value type to those that implement `Comparable`.  Something like this:

```
public class C<T extends Comparable<? super T>> extends Comparable<C<T>> {
    private final T value;

    @Override
    public int compareTo(C<T> that) {
       return this.value.compareTo(that.value);
    }
}
```

This only makes sense for some containers, such as those that simply wrap a value.

Comment: This suggestion also helps very much. Thanks.